# Wildfly 18 deploying war error - java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to remote+http://hostname:port

Tags: jboss, port, wildfly, jboss-eap-6, wildfly-18

I am deploying a war in my wildfly 18 server with below command -

$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=$HOSTNAME:$PORT --user=**** --password=****

Values for JBOSS_HOME, HOSTNAME and PORT were passed correct as per need, but I am getting this below error after running this -

**Failed to connect to the controller: The controller is not available at hostname:port: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to remote+http://hostname:port. The connection failed: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to remote+http://hostname:port. The connection failed: *Invalid response***

here port is the management-native port + offset, which are also properly defined in my standalone-ha.xml-

```html
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:20}">
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="45001"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="41001"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="41201"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="public" port="${jboss.management.http.port:51000}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="public" port="${jboss.management.https.port:51200}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="public" port="${jboss.management.native.port:43001}"/>
        .....
    </socket-binding-group>
```

**Can someone help me on this as I am new to wildfly 18 that what I am missing out here?**
My wildfly server is up and running, i am able to deploy my war from admin console of wildfly but getting error in putty(Linux).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using http+remote you should connect to management-http port and not the management-native one

Comment: yes it worked but I am bound to use management-native port for deployment, i checked my jboss-cli.xml it have - <default-controller>
        <host>localhost</host>
        <port>9990</port>
    </default-controller>
How can i change this http+remote to use management-native port only?

Comment: you need to switch protocol and use remote:// https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFCORE-296

Comment: @ShrishtiJain how did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to port 51020
As you have given offset of 20 and your management-http port is 51000.